# How to embedded chinese names (title, artist, year, genre and abum) in a mp3 file

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, utf-8, import

I am trying to embedded Chinese names (title, Artist, Year, Genre and Album) in a mp3 file. title names will be taken from a CSV file(which has Chinese data).

The code is working but the when i check the mp3 files details, every thing is shown in '?????' this is happening only when the data is in Chinese. But when the data is in English. its working fine. I have no idea whats going wrong in my code.

Please find the code below.

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser
from mutagen.easyid3 import EasyID3
from datetime import datetime
from string import Template
import os
import sys
import datetime
import codecs
import string
import shutil
import re
import logging
import io
import eyed3
import id3
import csv
 

# other
UTF8Writer = codecs.getwriter('utf8')
sys.stdout = UTF8Writer(sys.stdout)
 
save_stdout = sys.stdout  # save for restore

# default input filenames
filename_mp3_csv = "mp3_ArtTitAlbGenYer.csv"
outfile = open ('mp3_cop.cop', 'wb')
 
def get_args():
    """parse command line arguments"""
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-t", "--mp3template", help="filename of mp3 file to be used as template",default="template.mp3")
    parser.add_argument("-l", "--language", help="name of language folder e.g. enu", default="enu")
    parser.add_argument("-ic", "--mp3_scv", help="filename of csv file to be used as input", default="mp3_ArtTitAlbGenYer.csv")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args
 

########################################################################################################################
# main program

def something():
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        args = get_args()
        i=0
        while os.path.exists("%s.mp3" % i):
            i+=1
        fh = open("%s.mp3" % i, "w")
        shutil.copy2(args.mp3template, "%s.mp3" %i)
        audio = EasyID3("%s.mp3" %i)
 
        audio["title"] =Title
        audio["artist"] = Artist
        audio["album"] = Album
        audio["date"] = Year
        audio["genre"] = Genre
        audio["tracknumber"] = u"1"
 

        audio.save()
    return
# read mp3_csv    utf-8-sig ignores BOM \xef\xbb\xbf at begin of file
try:
    file = codecs.open(filename_mp3_csv, "r",encoding='utf-8-sig')
    for line in file:
       # print(' \n '.join(line))

        #print(len(line.rstrip().encode('utf8')))

       item = line.split(';')
       Artist = item[0].rstrip()
       Title = item[1].rstrip()
       Album = item[2].rstrip()
       Genre = item[3].rstrip()
       Year = item[4].rstrip()

 
       print(line.rstrip(';'))
 
       something()
 
    file.close()
 
except IOError as err:  # e.g. file not existing
    mustwritesomethinghere = 0
    print >> sys.stderr, "error: unable to read mandatory inputfile " + filename_mp3_csv
```

Comment: I have no idea what to do, because the code is working when the CSV file is having English data and but when it has Chinese data its not working

Comment: ¿Where are you checking the file? Maybe you aren't using the correct codec to read the properties. If you analize the file as binary ¿Are the records the same value, the equivalent to '?' or are different bytes? If them are different bytes, your problem is the codec that interpret the data.

Comment: I am using the CSV file in UTF8 format. and when I execute the code in pycharm shows me perfect output (Chinese format) in Run tool window. But when it comes to the mp3 file its showing me all the details in '?????'

Comment: Did you set the encoding in `mutagen.id3.Encoding`? http://mutagen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/id3.html#mutagen.id3.Encoding